# How to make a slider bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Aloha, I'm trying to develop a slider bar that has 3 words that you can choose from. But I'm not able to save the words as letters, all I get is number either 1,2 or 3 :(

Here's the code I have and also a picture:)

```
<form action="something.php" method="post" id="form">  
    <input type="range" min=1 max=3 step=1 name="slider"> 
        <div id="text"> 
            <span > Bad </span>
            <span> Ok </span>
            <span> Good </span>
        </div> 
        <input type="submit" value="next" id="but"/> 
    </input> 
</form>
```

So this code shows the slider bar and letters at the top (which works with my css), but when I click "Submit", on the following page (using php) I get 1, 2 or 3. 
But it should be Bad, Good or Good. I'm sure that the problem is in the HTML code.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just assign the numerals to values when you process the submission?

```
if(isset($_POST['slider'])) {
    $array[1] = 'Bad';
    $array[2] = 'Ok';
    $array[3] = 'Good';

    // This is a simplified output, but this is essentially
    // the easiest way
    echo $array[$_POST['slider']];
}
```

Comment: No problem. Sometimes the simplest solution is all you need! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by using html only.

You could create a hidden input field and a "change" event handler on the range input field. The event handler sets the value of the hidden input field to the label corresponding to the selected number (1: bad, 2: ok, 3: good).

Example:

```
<form action="something.php" method="post" id="form">  
    <input type="range" min=1 max=3 step=1 name="slider" id="slider">
    <input type="hidden" name="sliderLabel" id="sliderLabel" />
    <div id="text"> 
        <span > Bad </span>
        <span> Ok </span>
        <span> Good </span>
    </div> 
    <input type="submit" value="next" id="but" />
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
    // function to update the value of the hidden field
    updateSliderLabel = function() {
        var selectedValue = $('#slider').val();
        var selectedLabel = $('#text > span').eq(selectedValue-1).text();

        $('#sliderLabel').val(selectedLabel);
    }

    // when slider is changed, call the update function
    $('#slider').on('change', function() {
        updateSliderLabel();
    });

    // when page is loaded, call the update function
    updateSliderLabel();
})();
</script>
```

The advantage of this solution is, you can easily adopt your labels in the html code, you don't need to modify your php logic.

Answer (score 0):

There is two manner to do what you want :

**1 - html + javascript :**

You should add a `hidden input` in your form which before submitting your form you give it a value among the three : Bad, OK, Good according to the value of your slider.

**2 - php :**

```
<?php

    $slider_index = intval($_POST['slider']);
    $word = '';
    switch ($slider_index) {
        case 1:
            $word = 'Bad';
            break;
        case 2:
            $word = 'OK';
            break;
        case 3:
            $word = 'Good';
            break;
    }

?>
```